# Addition Assignment in C and C#?

Tags: c#, c

So, I'm learning the code for [the SplitMix64 generator](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/splitmix64.c) and came upon this part here:

```c
uint64_t z = (x += 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15);
```

Not being a C programmer, I don't really understand this construct.

Does the above mean z gets assigned value of x *after* x is incremented, like so:

```
x += 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15;
z = x;
```

Or does that mean z gets the value of x *before* x is incremented, like so:

```
z = x;
x += 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15;
```

And also, does the same behavior happen in C# ?

Comment: In C, the first is correct. `x` is updated and then copied to `z`.

Comment: In most languages, parenthesis mean reduce the expression within the parenthesis first. For such questions all you need to do is try it out and see what happens

Comment: @CodingYoshi yeah, you're right... I only just found out about https://repl.it/languages ... it's such a great resource, now I can experiment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z gets assigned value of x *after* x is incremented. Think of it like this:

```
z = (x = x + 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15);
```

The return value of an assignment is always the value of the left-hand side of the assignment after the assignment is completed.